# Is there a way to mount a local dir, by local I mean a dir from my laptop or a VM box, to k8s cluster running remotely

Tags: kubernetes, local

Is there a way to mount a local dir, by local I mean a dir from my laptop or a VM box, to k8s cluster. I read the k8s doc about local volume, doesn't look like what I want, a example or reference link would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for ksync https://github.com/ksync/ksync and devspace syncing https://github.com/devspace-cloud/devspace